# Intellij IDEA 12 only outputs the last line

Tags: intellij-idea, console, jboss7.x, output, logback

I'm running an application on JBoss AS7. When I start the server, all the init logs from JBoss are correctly shown in the Output view but the application logs aren't. I only have the last line that overrides the previous one.

The application logs are written to the console via logback :

```
<appender name="out" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
  <encoder>
    <Pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS}|%level|%thread|%logger{50}|%msg%n</Pattern>
  </encoder>
</appender>

<root level="info">
  <appender-ref ref="out" />
</root>
```

Here is the logging configuration in standalone.xml :

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:logging:1.1">
    <console-handler name="CONSOLE">
        <level name="INFO"/>
        <formatter>
            <pattern-formatter pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%E%n"/>
        </formatter>
    </console-handler>
    <logger category="com.arjuna">
        <level name="WARN"/>
    </logger>
    <logger category="org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler">
        <level name="WARN"/>
    </logger>
    <logger category="sun.rmi">
        <level name="WARN"/>
    </logger>
    <logger category="jacorb">
        <level name="WARN"/>
    </logger>
    <logger category="jacorb.config">
        <level name="ERROR"/>
    </logger>
    <root-logger>
        <level name="INFO"/>
        <handlers>
            <handler name="CONSOLE"/>
        </handlers>
    </root-logger>
</subsystem>
```

If I save the log to a file, I can see all my application logs. I tried to increase the buffer but it didn't work. The same configuration works on Eclipse.

As en example, this is what I get in Intellij ouptput :

```
...                // logs from JBoss
deployed appli ... // logs from JBoss
log3               // logs from application (logback)
```

And the same thing if logged into a file :

```
...                // logs from JBoss
deployed appli ... // logs from JBoss
log1               // logs from application (logback)
log2               // logs from application (logback)
log3               // logs from application (logback)
```

log3 overrided log1 and log2.

Comment: Where is logback being used? Are you including logback in your application along with a logback configuration?

Comment: It is included in the application. We are using SLF4J with logback as implementation. The logback.xml is in classpath. The same configuration works with Eclipse. The problem only appears in Output window of Intellij. If I configure the Intellij JBoss run configuration to save console output to a file, the file contains all the logs as expected.

Comment: I wonder if it's the way it redirects stdout. The application server redirects it to a logger. Maybe there is some kind of issue there.

Comment: As a workaround, I tell logback to write to a file instead of console and configure my run configuration to show that log file. I'll try to remove the console handler from JBoss and see if it works.